# how to nest createDrawerNavigator createStackNavigator createBottomTabNavigator

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I have tried many ways, but I have not found a good solution to nest createDrawerNavigator  createBottomTabNavigator createStackNavigator

## now

- Drawer (createDrawerNavigator)

  - MainStack(createStackNavigator)
  - TabNav(createBottomTabNavigator)

    - HomeScreen
    - StructureScreen
    - ClassifyScreen
    - ProjectScreen
  - DetailScreen
  - LoginScreen
  - RegisterScreen
  - AboutMeScreen
  - CollectScreen
  - LoginScreen
  - AboutMeScreen
  - CollectScreen

When i open drawer in MainStack, then click AboutMe open AboutMeScreen , at this time is in the AboutMeScreen , but when i open drawer , focus is **MainStack** 
- Why focus item is **MainStack** ? I think should be **AboutMe** at this time.

[here is my code](https://github.com/SilenceBurst/ReactNative_WanAndroid/blob/master/src/navigator/DrawerNav.js)

---

## previous

- Drawer(createDrawerNavigator)

  - MainStack(createStackNavigator)
  - TabNav(createBottomTabNavigator)

    - HomeScreen
    - StructureScreen
    - ClassifyScreen
    - ProjectScreen
  - DetailScreen
  - LoginStack(createStackNavigator)
  - LoginScreen
  - RegisterScreen
  - AboutMeStack(createStackNavigator)
  - AboutMeScreen
  - CollectStack(createStackNavigator)
  - CollectScreen

In this way , when i open drawer in MainStack , then click AboutMe open AboutMeScreen 
- AboutMeStack don't have headerLeft to goBack

and , when i open drawer in MainStack , then open LoginScreen , then open RegisterScreen 
- I don't know how to direct navigate to MainStack .

---

I don't know which method is right . 
My English is not very good , and first learn react-native , Thanks

#### Your Environment

| software         | version
| ---------------- | -------
| react-navigation | 2.2.0
| react-native     | 0.55.4

Comment: Have you found any way to solve this? Currently on version 2.17 and same problem.

Answer (score 1):

these step will help

i am given my example

step 1: App.js file i have following code (createStackNavigator)

```
import HomeScreen from './src/component/Home/homescreen';
.....

const AuthStack = createStackNavigator({
Home : {
       screen: HomeActivity,
          navigationOptions: {
             header:null        
          }
       },
Profile:  LoginScreen,
Signup: SignupScreen,
});

const AppStack = createStackNavigator(
    {
        HomeScene: HomeScreen,
        ChooseWallet: ChooseWalletScreen,
        ChooseFiatSrn:ChooseFiatScreen,
    });


export default createSwitchNavigator(
{
  App:AppStack,
  Auth:AuthStack,
},
{
  initialRouteName:'Auth',
});
```

setp 2: homescreen.js i have following code (createBottomTabNavigator,createDrawerNavigator)

```
import Ionicons from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons';
....

const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator({
      Wallet: WalletScreen,
      Request: RequestScreen,
      Send: SendScreen,
      Exchange: ExchangeScreen,
},
{   
    navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
    tabBarIcon: ({ focused, tintColor }) => {
    const { routeName } = navigation.state;
    let iconName;
    if (routeName === 'Wallet') {
      iconName = `ios-home`;
    } else if (routeName === 'Request') {
      iconName = `ios-options`;
    }else if (routeName === 'Send') {
        iconName = `ios-send`;
    }else if (routeName === 'Exchange') {
        iconName = `ios-swap`;
    }
    // You can return any component that you like here! We usually use an
    // icon component from react-native-vector-icons
    return <Ionicons name={iconName} size={25} color={tintColor} />;
  },
}),
tabBarOptions: {
    activeTintColor: 'steelblue',
    inactiveTintColor: 'gray',  
  },
});

 const DrawerNavigation = createDrawerNavigator({
  Home:{
        screen: Tab,
        //Add can more screen
       }
  });
  export default DrawerNavigation;
```

if anyone face any issue then let me help you